# UTF-8: lendo e inserindo no MySQL via Ruby 1.8

Tags: mysql, ruby, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou usando um script escrito em Ruby que faz 'parse' de uns arquivos XML e insere as informações num bando MySQL. Ele funciona perfeitamente bem, mas está me dando dor de cabeça agora que meus arquivos XML têm strings em português.

Detalhe: sou completamente novato em Ruby.

Por alguns motivos estou preso ao Ruby 1.8 e andei lendo que esta versão tem peculiaridades para lidar com Strings. Já confirmei que tanto o arquivo XML como o 'collation' do MySQL e tabelas são UTF-8.

Também já tentei, sem sucesso, codificar o string antes de mandar para o banco usando uma dica encontrada [neste post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583924) da seguinte forma:

```
@text = ::Iconv.conv('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8', attributes['Text'] + ' ')[0..-2]
```

Depois de inserir os dados olho via PHPMyAdmin que os strings estão pirados. Por exemplo: 'nÃ³s' ao invés de 'não'.

Alguma ideia de como posso abordar o problema?

Comment: E qual seria, a sua collation da tua tabela? por que muitas vezes a collation do banco e da tabela são diferentes... Só confirma isso..

Comment: Valeu @BrunoCasali - pra ser mais específico: utf8_general_ci

Comment: Humm, beleza, tu experimentou digamos serializar em outro arquivo xml, txt ou gravar em outro banco ou simplesmente mostrar na tela sem ser com o banco ?

Comment: Opa @BrunoCasali. Não tinha tentado e só pude ver agora. Quando imprimo na tela acho que o próprio sistema de saída trata a codificação de caracteres pois no terminal o string sai correto. =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por fim resolvi.

Acaba que o problema era do driver de conexão com o banco. Através [desta resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17575736) vi a recomendação da utilização do 'mysql2' ao invés do 'mysql' pois a 2 trata a codificação de caracteres corretamente!

Comment: Show de bola!! :D

Comment: Legal, apenas marque a sua resposta como correta para auxiliar os usuários que estão buscando essa informação.

Comment: Beleza @Andrey. Tô só esperando o tempo requerido pelo sistema. Só posso marcar amanhã. Abraço.

Comment: @Nigini Só pode marcar amanhã? Não sabia desta restrição.

Comment: Se não me engano é para promover a diversidade. Se eu pergunto, respondo e resolvo, o resto da comunidade vai ter menos interesse em responder. =/